# Poner un Modal que se encuentra en otro archivo php hacia un archivo php "principal"

Tags: jquery, modal, crud

estoy realizando un CRUD, en mi pagina donde administro los usuarios hay un formulario  y delante de cada usuario hay un boton para actualizar los datos y otro para eliminar, a estos botones les quiero implementar un modal el cual cuando se abre muestra un formulario con los datos del usuario seleccionado para realizar la accion necesaria, ya sea actualizarlo o eliminarlo.

El problema que tengo es que como estoy utilizando href en los botones antes mencionados evidentemente me actualiza la pagina y es lo que no quiero, lo que quiero es que aparezca el MODAL en donde administro los usuarios, pero que el formulario del MODAL jale los datos en el formulario.

Adjunto el codigo:
AQUI ES DONDE ADMINISTRO LOS USUARIOS

```
 <?php
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/dt/datatables.min.css" />
    <link href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container-fluid" style="margin-top:30px !important;">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row mb-2">
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    <h1>Administrador de Usuarios<p id="fechayhora"></p></h1>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <button type="button" id="insert-btn" class="btn btn-primary" style="float: right;">
                        <i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card mb-3" id="form-body">
                <div class="card-header">
                    Nuevo Registro
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <form>
                        <div class="form-group mt-2">
                            <label>Nombre</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombre" maxlength="8" placeholder="Ingrese su Nombre(s)">

                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group mt-2">
                            <label>Apellido Paterno</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="appaterno" placeholder="Ingrese su Apellido Paterno">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group mt-2">
                            <label>Apellido Materno</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="apmaterno" placeholder="Ingrese su Apellido Materno">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group mt-2"> 
                        <label>Usuario</label> 
             <input type="email" class="form-control" id="usuario"  pattern=".+@te\.gob\.mx" placeholder="Usuario">
        </div>
                        <div class="form-group mt-2">
                            <label>Área</label>
                            <input type="text" multiple class="form-control" onkeyup="search_areas()" id="area" list="lista_areas"
                            required placeholder="Ingrese su Área">
                            <?php
                                require_once('conexion.php');
                                $sql = 'SELECT fi_area_id, fc_nom_area FROM tbl_areas WHERE fi_status_a=1'; 
                                $resultado = pg_query( $conexion, $sql );  
                            ?>    
                            <datalist id="lista_areas">
                                <?php while($areas = pg_fetch_assoc($resultado)) { ?>
                                <option value="<?php echo $areas['fc_nom_area']; ?>"></option>
                                <?php } ?>
                            </datalist>
                        </div>

                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mt-2" id="registrar">Registrar</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <?php

                require_once('conexion.php');
                $sql = "SELECT fc_usr, concat(fc_nom,' ', fc_app,' ', fc_apm) as nombrec, fc_area from tbl_usuarios WHERE fi_status = 1;";
                $result = pg_query($conexion,$sql);
                
            ?>
            <table id="tblUser">
                <thead>
                    <th>Usuario</th>
                    <th>Nombre</th>
                    <th>Área</th>
                    <th>Modificar</th>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <?php while($tuser = pg_fetch_assoc($result)) { ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td><?php echo $tuser['fc_usr']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $tuser['nombrec']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $tuser['fc_area']; ?></td>
                            <td>
                             
                                <a href="actualizar_form.php?id=<?php echo $tuser['fc_usr']; ?>" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i></a>
                                <a href="eliminar_form.php?id=<?php echo $tuser['fc_usr']; ?>" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>
                               
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    <?php }  ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
     
    <script src="js/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/dt/datatables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $('#tblUser').DataTable();
        $("#form-body").hide();

        $("#insert-btn").on('click',function(){
            $("#form-body").toggle(500);
        });

        $("#registrar").on('click',function(e){
            e.preventDefault();

            var vnombre = $('#nombre').val();
            var vappaterno = $('#appaterno').val();
            var vapmaterno = $('#apmaterno').val();
            var vusuario = $('#usuario').val();
            var varea = $('#area').val();
            //nombre appaterno apmaterno usuario area

            $.ajax({
                url : "insertar.php",
                type : "POST",
                data : {nombre:vnombre,appaterno:vappaterno,apmaterno:vapmaterno,usuario:vusuario,area:varea},
                cache: false
            })
            .done(function (data) { 
                console.log(data);
                
                if(data == data){
                    alert('Registro exitoso');
                }else{
                    alert(data);
                }

                $("#form-body").hide();
                location.reload(true);
             })
            .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
                alert('Error: '+xhr.status+' '+thrownError);
             });
        });
    } );
    </script>
    <script>  setInterval(fechayhora, 1000); </script>
    <script>
        function search_areas() {
            let input = document.getElementById('area').value
            input=input.toLowerCase();
            let x = document.getElementsByClassName('areas');
            
            for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) { 
                if (!x[i].innerHTML.toLowerCase().includes(input)) {
                    x[i].style.display="none";
                }
                
                else {
                    x[i].style.display="list-item";                 
                }
            }
        }
    </script>  

</body>
</html>

Y ESTE EL EL CODIGO DEL MODAL

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/dt/datatables.min.css" />
    <link href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    
<?php  require_once('conexion.php'); ?>
<?php 
        $vid =  ( empty($_GET['id']) ) ? NULL : $_GET['id'];
        $vid = pg_escape_string($vid);
       //echo "valor: ".$vid;
        $query = "SELECT fc_usr, fc_nom, fc_app, fc_apm, fc_area FROM tbl_usuarios WHERE fc_usr='$vid' AND fi_status=1;";
        $result = pg_query($conexion,$query);
        //echo "consulta: ".$query;
?>


    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary bt-sm" id="actualizar" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#staticBackdrop"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i>
    </button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered"  id="staticBackdrop" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel">

  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="staticBackdropLabel">Actualizar datos</h1>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body" id="modal-body">
        <form>
          <?php while($tusuarios = pg_fetch_assoc($result)) { ?>      
                <label>Nombre</label>
                <div class="form-group mt-2">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="act_nom"  maxlength="10" value="<?php echo $tusuarios['fc_nom']; ?>"> 
                </div>
                <div class="form-group mt-2">
                    <label>Apellido Paterno</label>
                    <input type="text"   class="form-control" id="act_app" maxlength="10" value="<?php echo $tusuarios['fc_app']; ?>"> 
                </div>
                <div class="form-group mt-2">
                    <label>Apellido Materno</label>
                    <input type="text"  class="form-control" id="act_apm" maxlength="10" value="<?php echo $tusuarios['fc_apm']; ?>"> 
                </div>  
                <div class="form-group mt-2">
                    
                    <input type="hidden"  class="form-control" id="vid" maxlength="10" value="<?php echo $tusuarios['fc_usr']; ?>"> 
                </div> 
                <div class="form-group mt-2">
                    <label>Área</label>
                    <input type="text" multiple class="form-control" onkeyup="search_areas()" id="act_area" list="lista_areas2"
                    required value="<?php echo $tusuarios['fc_area']; ?>">
                    <?php
                        $sql = 'SELECT fi_area_id, fc_nom_area FROM tbl_areas WHERE fi_status_a=1'; 
                        $resultado = pg_query( $conexion, $sql );  
                    ?>    
                    <datalist id="lista_areas2">
                        <?php while($areas = pg_fetch_assoc($resultado)) { ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $areas['fc_nom_area']; ?>"></option>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </datalist>
                    
                </div>
          <?php }  ?>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="aceptar">Aceptar</button>
      </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.6/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-oBqDVmMz9ATKxIep9tiCxS/Z9fNfEXiDAYTujMAeBAsjFuCZSmKbSSUnQlmh/jp3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="js/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>

<script>
    

    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
 
        $("#aceptar").on('click',function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var mnombre = $("#act_nom").val();
            var mappaterno = $("#act_app").val();
            var mapmaterno = $("#act_apm").val();
            var mid = $("#vid").val();
            var marea = $("#act_area").val();
        
            $.ajax({
                url : "actualizar.php",
                type : "POST",
                data : {act_nom:mnombre,act_app:mappaterno,act_apm:mapmaterno,vid:mid,act_area:marea},
                cache: false
            })
            .done(function (data) { 
                console.log(data);
                
                if(data == data){
                    alert('Cambio Realizado');
                }else{
                    alert(data);
                }

                $("#modal-body").hide();
                location.reload(true);
             })
            .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
                alert('Error: '+xhr.status+' '+thrownError);
             });
        });
    } );

    </script>

</body>
</html>

Espero me puedan ayudar
```

Answer (score 0):

No sé si lo resolviste, intentaré dejarte pasos sencillos, si aún tienes dudas puedes comentar mi respuesta:

1. Crea un botón el cuál genere una petición AJAX y mandes como data el ID del usuario
2. En tu archivo php "consultar_empleado.php", genera la consulta a la
   base de datos y regresala a AJAX en response como JSON
3. Cuando la petición reciba el response, carga los datos a los campos
   correspondientes que quieres mostrar y editar, estos campos estará dentro del form

Este formulario esta dentro del modal, entonces para mostrar el modal puedes usar el metodo modal()

```
$(selector).modal('show');
```

Reitero, si tienes dudas aún, deja tu comentario